# Search a word in HTML's tag <title> with oracle

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-text

must create a query which searches a world only in HTML's tag .
I create the following table disegnilegge

```
Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------ -------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
CODICE                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)                                                                                                                                                                                   
URL                                     VARCHAR2(100)
```

where codice is the primary key.
Successively I filled disegnilegge in this way

```
select * from disegnilegge;

CODICE URL                                                                                                  
------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
001/18 https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norma_giuridica                                                        
002/18 https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atto_normativo                                                         
003/18 https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paperino                                                               
004/18 http://www.inf.uniroma3.it/~patrigna/didactic/imp_elab/esempi_html/index.html
```

I also created the following index

```
create index parlamento2018.idx_testo_ddl
on parlamento2018.disegnilegge(url) indextype is
ctxsys.context;
```

How do I proceed now?

Comment: I presume you'd proceed by writing a SELECT statement. What result do you expect to get, based on values you stored into that table?

Comment: I want a select which displayes me the row where are present some words or characters which are presente in HTML's tag title.
E.g.: if the carachter is "-" the select will return
    CODICE URL                                                                                                  
    001/18 https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norma_giuridica                                                        
    002/18 https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atto_normativo                                                         
    003/18 https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paperino